# nodemon command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, nodemon

When i input "nodemon", i get the following error: "bash: nodemon: command not found". I've tried installing it both locally and globally, and it actuall worked yesterday, and I can't remember what I've changed so that it doesn't work anymore. I am using the Git Bash shell.

When i install nodemon, i get the following output:

```
$ npm install nodemon --save
webdev@1.0.0 C:\users\corfi\Google Drive\coding\webdev\site
`-- nodemon@1.11.0
  +-- chokidar@1.7.0
  | +-- anymatch@1.3.2
  | | +-- micromatch@2.3.11
  | | | +-- arr-diff@2.0.0
  | | | | `-- arr-flatten@1.1.0
  | | | +-- array-unique@0.2.1
  | | | +-- braces@1.8.5
  | | | | +-- expand-range@1.8.2
  | | | | | `-- fill-range@2.2.3
  | | | | |   +-- is-number@2.1.0
  | | | | |   +-- isobject@2.1.0
  | | | | |   `-- randomatic@1.1.7
  | | | | |     +-- is-number@3.0.0
  | | | | |     | `-- kind-of@3.2.2
  | | | | |     `-- kind-of@4.0.0
  | | | | +-- preserve@0.2.0
  | | | | `-- repeat-element@1.1.2
  | | | +-- expand-brackets@0.1.5
  | | | | `-- is-posix-bracket@0.1.1
  | | | +-- extglob@0.3.2
  | | | +-- filename-regex@2.0.1
  | | | +-- object.omit@2.0.1
  | | | | +-- for-own@0.1.5
  | | | | | `-- for-in@1.0.2
  | | | | `-- is-extendable@0.1.1
  | | | +-- parse-glob@3.0.4
  | | | | +-- glob-base@0.3.0
  | | | | `-- is-dotfile@1.0.3
  | | | `-- regex-cache@0.4.3
  | | |   +-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3
  | | |   `-- is-primitive@2.0.0
  | | `-- normalize-path@2.1.1
  | |   `-- remove-trailing-separator@1.0.2
  | +-- async-each@1.0.1
  | +-- glob-parent@2.0.0
  | +-- is-binary-path@1.0.1
  | | `-- binary-extensions@1.10.0
  | +-- is-glob@2.0.1
  | | `-- is-extglob@1.0.0
  | `-- readdirp@2.1.0
  |   `-- set-immediate-shim@1.0.1
  +-- ignore-by-default@1.0.1
  +-- lodash.defaults@3.1.2
  | +-- lodash.assign@3.2.0
  | | +-- lodash._baseassign@3.2.0
  | | | `-- lodash._basecopy@3.0.1
  | | +-- lodash._createassigner@3.1.1
  | | | +-- lodash._bindcallback@3.0.1
  | | | `-- lodash._isiterateecall@3.0.9
  | | `-- lodash.keys@3.1.2
  | |   +-- lodash._getnative@3.9.1
  | |   +-- lodash.isarguments@3.1.0
  | |   `-- lodash.isarray@3.0.4
  | `-- lodash.restparam@3.6.1
  +-- ps-tree@1.1.0
  | `-- event-stream@3.3.4
  |   +-- duplexer@0.1.1
  |   +-- from@0.1.7
  |   +-- map-stream@0.1.0
  |   +-- pause-stream@0.0.11
  |   +-- split@0.3.3
  |   +-- stream-combiner@0.0.4
  |   `-- through@2.3.8
  +-- touch@1.0.0
  | `-- nopt@1.0.10
  |   `-- abbrev@1.1.0
  +-- undefsafe@0.0.3
  `-- update-notifier@0.5.0
    +-- chalk@1.1.3
    | +-- ansi-styles@2.2.1
    | +-- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
    | +-- has-ansi@2.0.0
    | | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
    | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
    | `-- supports-color@2.0.0
    +-- configstore@1.4.0
    | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
    | | `-- minimist@0.0.8
    | +-- object-assign@4.1.1
    | +-- os-tmpdir@1.0.2
    | +-- osenv@0.1.4
    | | `-- os-homedir@1.0.2
    | +-- uuid@2.0.3
    | +-- write-file-atomic@1.3.4
    | | +-- imurmurhash@0.1.4
    | | `-- slide@1.1.6
    | `-- xdg-basedir@2.0.0
    +-- is-npm@1.0.0
    +-- latest-version@1.0.1
    | `-- package-json@1.2.0
    |   +-- got@3.3.1
    |   | +-- duplexify@3.5.1
    |   | | +-- end-of-stream@1.4.0
    |   | | `-- stream-shift@1.0.0
    |   | +-- infinity-agent@2.0.3
    |   | +-- is-redirect@1.0.0
    |   | +-- is-stream@1.1.0
    |   | +-- lowercase-keys@1.0.0
    |   | +-- nested-error-stacks@1.0.2
    |   | +-- object-assign@3.0.0
    |   | +-- prepend-http@1.0.4
    |   | +-- read-all-stream@3.1.0
    |   | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
    |   | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
    |   | `-- timed-out@2.0.0
    |   `-- registry-url@3.1.0
    |     `-- rc@1.2.1
    |       +-- deep-extend@0.4.2
    |       +-- ini@1.3.4
    |       +-- minimist@1.2.0
    |       `-- strip-json-comments@2.0.1
    +-- repeating@1.1.3
    | `-- is-finite@1.0.2
    |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1
    +-- semver-diff@2.1.0
    `-- string-length@1.0.1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN webdev@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: Did you try executing nodemon from its folder in node modules?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Navigate to the node_modules/nodemon/bin/ folder and executing from there? I just tried that, and i get the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to install nodemon globally

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Windows sometimes looses references in environment. If you´re using Windows 10, try to find nodemon.js in "C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin". Then copy this path and execute

```
node THE_PATH\nodemon.js YOUR_COOL_APP.js
```

It´s a workaround, but it usually works.
Hope it helps...

Comment: Well, it worked, meaning i can now launch the server through nodemon, but it doesn't actually do what it's supposed to do, i just noticed (It doesn't update on changes.)

Comment: Probably you have environment issues. Check environment variables, registry keys etc. For me that workaround works fine! Windows... argh!

Comment: but can i add this path to my path variable because everytime i have to use this address to use nodemon .plz explain me how to add this path to path variable .

Comment: @anish-mathew has provided acceptable solution that resolves problem permanently.

Answer (score 0):

go to the directory you want to use nodemon, then use the path to where nodemon is installed in your node modules instead of just nodemon. i.e.

```
c:/user/[your path here]/nodemon [your node app]
```

instead of

```
nodemon [your node app]
```

Comment: Output says no such directory, but I am certain it is the directory which has nodemon.js:  `$ C:/user/corfi/"Google Drive"/coding/webdev/site/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon server.js
bash: C:/user/corfi/Google Drive/coding/webdev/site/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have to find out the location where nodemon is installed and then add its path in path variable.

> C:\ >npm config get prefix
>
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> C:\ >set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;

You have to run this on command prompt.